# Android sharing file

Tags: android, file

I would like to share a file from internal directory. 
I already use file provider.

```
        <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.gps.stuttgartuni.bincalendar"
        android:exported="true"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_path" />
    </provider>
```

and I share the file like this

```
            File file = new File(getFilesDir(), fileName);
    if(file.exists()){
        try {
            Uri uri =FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(), BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID, file);
            Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sharingIntent.setType("application/xml");

            sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
            sharingIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            Context context=getApplicationContext();
            List<ResolveInfo> resInfoList = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(sharingIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
            for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resInfoList) {
                String packageName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
                context.grantUriPermission(packageName, uri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            }
            startActivity(sharingIntent);
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("Error",e.getMessage());
        }
```

I am trying to send .xml
The code has no problems with sending e-mail using gmail and build in client, but I can't share the file using what's app or messenger, or any other messaging app.
Same messenger apps show the toast that the format is unsupported although normally I can send .xml file using them.

Any idea why the code has problem only with some apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happen because you are set `sharingIntent.setType("application/xml");` and not all apps can handle your intent. Change your type to `sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");`

Comment: It works. I had also another problem with copping the file which causes this one.Thank you.